# How can i make an a footer and the name in the had?

Tags: html, css

I need to make the name: Data Science in the header and in the footer i need to make
an a Steve Jacob. How can i make this, if i try it looks like wery bad it overlaps the left menu. There is how cite looks like:
[image]
There is my index.html:

Again, how can i make some notice in the footer and header which doesn't overlaps the left menu.

```css
imgsize {
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  margin-left: 30%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Главная</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700,800,900" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/style.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper d-flex align-items-stretch">
    <nav id="sidebar">
      <div class="custom-menu">
        <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-primary">
              <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle Menu</span>
            </button>
      </div>
      <div class="p-4 pt-5">
        <ul class="list-unstyled components mb-5">
          <a href="/"><img class="imgsize" src="{% static 'media/logo.png' %}" alt=""></a>
          <li class="active">
            <a href="/">Главная</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Востребованность</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">География</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Навыки</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Последние вакансии</a>
          </li>
        </ul>



        <div class="footer">
          <p>
            <!-- Link back to Colorlib can't be removed. Template is licensed under CC BY 3.0. -->
            
            
            <!-- Link back to Colorlib can't be removed. Template is licensed under CC BY 3.0. -->
          </p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Page Content  -->
    <div id="content" class="p-4 p-md-5 pt-5">

      <h2 class="mb-4">Sidebar #02</h2>

    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="static/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="static/js/popper.js"></script>
  <script src="static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="static/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
<footer>

</footer>
```

Comment: Do you have a minimum code to work with. The files style.css and main.js are not shown, and probably to big to shopw in the question.